# Compound meter in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

It is needed to adjust the meter in the second instrument for compound meter, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=22mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.95\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%\begin{adjustbox}{width=.6\textwidth,center}
%\resizebox{0.46\textwidth}{!}{%
%\scalebox{0.6}{
%\framebox{
\begin{tikzpicture}%[thick, scale=0.5, every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {
\begin{music}
        \parindent3mm
        \instrumentnumber{2}
        \setstaffs1{1}
        \setstaffs2{1}
        %\hsize=\musicwidth
        \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
        \setclef2\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 2
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 4/4
        \setinterstaff{1}{14}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \Notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en\setdoublebar
        \generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}{4}}\changecontext
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en\setdoublebar
        \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}\changecontext
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en 
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en
        \setdoubleBAR
        \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}
};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        %Código para grillas
        %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        %Dibujando lineas y texto
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (-0.09,0.55) -- (-0.09,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.05,0.55) -- (0.05,0.4);
        
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.27,0.55) -- (0.27,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.41,0.55) -- (0.41,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.55,0.55) -- (0.55,0.4);

        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.77,0.55) -- (0.77,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.91,0.55) -- (0.91,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (1.05,0.55) -- (1.05,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (1.18,0.55) -- (1.18,0.4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}
%\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The expected output should be (note that 2/4 should be replaced by 6/8, and so on):
[image: expected]

Comment: There is a quite clear instruction how to do place different meters to different instruments in the manual.

Comment: Can you share the example? which page?

Comment: Acually, I could, but i think you should study the manual yourself. Various of your questions can be answered by doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According Daunaf support, the code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=22mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.95\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[thick, scale=0.5, every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {
\begin{music}
        \parindent3mm
        \instrumentnumber{2}
        \setstaffs1{1}
        \setstaffs2{1}
        %\hsize=\musicwidth
        \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
        \setclef2\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 2
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        %\generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}4} %Compás en 4/4
        \setmeter2{{\meterfrac{2}{4}}}%
        \setmeter1{{\meterfrac{6}{8}}}%\changecontext
        \setinterstaff{1}{14}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        \Notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en\setdoublebar
        %\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}{4}}\changecontext
        \setmeter2{{\meterfrac{3}{4}}}%
        \setmeter1{{\meterfrac{9}{8}}}\changecontext
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en\setdoublebar
        %\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}\changecontext
        \setmeter2{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}%
        \setmeter1{{\meterfrac{12}{8}}}\changecontext
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} \en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en 
        \notes \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qup j\qb0{f}\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*} & \ibl0f0 \zqb0{f}\qu j\tbl0\zqb0{f} \qu {*}\en
        \setdoubleBAR
        \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}
};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        %Código para grillas
        %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        %Dibujando lineas y texto
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (-0.09,0.55) -- (-0.09,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.05,0.55) -- (0.05,0.4);
        
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.27,0.55) -- (0.27,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.41,0.55) -- (0.41,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.55,0.55) -- (0.55,0.4);

        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.77,0.55) -- (0.77,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (0.91,0.55) -- (0.91,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (1.05,0.55) -- (1.05,0.4);
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt,red] (1.18,0.55) -- (1.18,0.4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: solved]

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitely set the meters according to chapter 15.4 Meter changes, p. 76 of musixdoc.pdf.

```
\setmeter2{{\meterfrac{2}{4}}}%

\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{6}{8}}}\changecontext
```

...

```
%\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}{4}}\changecontext

\setmeter2{{\meterfrac{3}{4}}}%

\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{9}{8}}}\changecontext
```

...

```
%\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}\changecontext

\setmeter2{{\meterfrac{4}{4}}}%

\setmeter1{{\meterfrac{12}{8}}}\changecontext
```